# Can I add Intel WiDi to a desktop computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, display

Is there any way to add Intel's WiDi technology to a desktop computer, or a laptop?

I'm thinking about setting up a Home Theater PC but I'd like to be able to mirror my computer to it easily.

Comment: Of course its possible.   Its just a matter having the supported hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do so with newer generation hardware. Do you have a computer that you intend to use or are you shopping for a computer? If you are still shopping, I'd strongly recommend getting a notebook (dare I say ultrabook) computer with the latest generation processor that is Intel Wi-Di certified.

> Intel® Wireless Display requires a desktop system based on a 3rd generation Intel® Core™ Processor. Intel® Wireless Display does not function on other desktop systems.

Source: [Intel Support](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/sb/CS-033372.htm)

Comment: Is it possible to look at the edit history of an answer on superuser or on so in general?

Comment: Na, I was hoping to add it to an existing computer. Thanks for the information, though.

Answer (score 2):

It can work, but in my experience doesn't work well. Wrote up a case study here: http://blog.jasonsamuels.net/post/51572141221/an-adventure-in-wireless-display-technology

Comment: Hi, Jason. Please disclose your link to the blog otherwise the communuity tends to flag self-promition as spam. Please see the [FaQ] section on promotion for more info.